# an equation to calculate all possible combinations in a table of data

Tags: permutations, combinations

let's say we have a table with N rows and M columns. each field can be yes or no. 
lets' say number of yes fields are K.
We want to calculate how many combinations of yes fields are in this table.
like a subset of brute force. It can in form of factorial, combinations, permutations. etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $NM\choose K$? Out of the $NM$ fields, there are exactly $k$ of them which are "yes" fields.

Comment: I think it cabe repeated, how about (NxM+k-1 choose K) = (NxM+k-1)! / (NxM)! x (k-1)!

Comment: What can be repeated? You are just choosing $K$ of the $NM$ cells to be "yes", and leaving the rest to be "no", That is $NM \choose K$, just as MPW said.